# WebApi versioning by custom header (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning & Swagger) not generating Swagger docs for endpoints using the same route

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui, autorest

I'm trying to version my WebApi's endpoints using Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning.
I added the [ApiVersion] attribute to the controllers
[image]

and I configured SwaggerConfig.cs as it follows:
[image]

...

[image]

WebApiConfig.cs
[image]

two of those endpoints have the **same route "users/all"**, one in "v1" controller and other in "v2" controller

Everything was going ok, **I'm able to reach the two different endpoints that contain the same routes** (users/all) **via POSTMAN app**,
passing the "api-version" custom header.

The problem is, when I try to do it **via Swagger UI, it does not identifies the "v2" endpoint** in the UI, so that, **I'm not able to try it via Swagger UI**,
and also, I'm **not able to generate the "v2" endpoint client via AutoRest**.

**Summarizing**: I'm not able to generate Swagger UI's docs or AutoRest client classes, for endpoints w/ same route (users/all),
when versioning the webapi via custom Headers.

Could you guys help me please? Thanks in advance.